# Selenium 2 - Switching focus to a frame that has no name/id

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

So right now I'm trying to figure out how I can switch focus to a frame in Selenium 2 when the frame has no name or id? For a named frame I do:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(FrameName);
```

but what is there is no name? Has anyone had experience with this?

Comment: You can just give the id of your iframe instead of iframe-name   Please see my below example, it worked for me.                                                                <iframe id="topframe" height="83px" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="NO" '1331808552380'"="" +="" src="initialize.do?init=header&cacheBuster=" name="topframe" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">

Answer (score 11, accepted):

driver.switchTo.frame() is [overloaded to accept a frame name or an integer](http://webdriver.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame(int)). This int is a 0 based index of the frames available. The first frame would be 0, the second 1 and so on.

I've just run a really quick test using the java binding and Firefox against this HTML page.

```
<html>
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
    <frame src="frame_a.htm" />
    <frame src="frame_b.htm" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

I'm successfully able to use driver.switchTo().frame(0); to refer to frame a and
driver.switchTo().frame(1); to access frame b.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index of the frame. Since you don't have name and id for the frame,
driver.switchTo().frame(int frameIndex)

Answer (score 0):

In selenium if you know that the relative location of the frame you should be able to use the selectFrame command with the string "relative=up" to move it up a frame e.g. `selenium.SelectFrame("relative=up");` or to jump to the top frame use "relative=top"

Comment: Do you know if this exists in Selenium 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the id of your iframe instead of iframe-name.

Please see my below example, it worked for me.
In the example I am switching to one iframe in my page and clicking on the element in that iframe, which is "worksheet0" .

Use the code :

```
driver.switchTo().frame("topframe");    
    WebElement worksheet0 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='reportSelect:Worksheet_lbl']"));               worksheet0.click();
```

The HTMLof the iframe :

```
  < iframe id="topframe" height="83px" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="NO" '1331808552380'"="" +="" src="initialize.do?init=header&cacheBuster=" name="topframe" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the index (as the other answers suggest), in **C#** you can select the iFrame by tagName. My example assumes there is one and only one iFrame on the page.

```
try
{
    var iFrameElement = Driver.FindElementByTagName("iFrame");
    var driver = Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(this.iFrameElement);    
    var element = driver.FindElement(selector);

    // do what you need with the element
}
finally
{
    // don't forget to switch back to the DefaultContent
    Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
}
```

Note: You have to get the information from the IWebElement .Text or .Click for example, before calling Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

I created these extensions methods to help

```
public static IWebDriver SwitchToIFrame(this RemoteWebDriver driver)
{
    // http://computerrecipes.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/selenium-webdriver-interact-with-an-element-inside-an-iframe/
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549584/selenium-2-switching-focus-to-a-frame-that-has-no-name-id
    var iFrameElement = driver.FindElementByTagName("iFrame");
    return driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iFrameElement);
}

public static void SwitchOutOfIFrame(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
}
```

An example of using the extensions methods:

```
public void ClickPrintButton()
{
    var iFrameDriver = Browser.Driver.SwitchToIFrame();
    try
    {
        iFrameDriver.FindElement(By.Id("saveButton")).Click();
    }
    finally
    {
        Browser.Driver.SwitchOutOfIFrame();
    }
}
```