# Selenium: Select a div Element using java

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium

I have to select "Module Name" in the below code using selenium can anybody help me?

```
<iframe width="142" height="225" frameborder="0"
        disabled="true" src="blank.htm" scrolling="no">
   <div style="position: absolute; visibility: inherit; overflow: hidden; cursor: default; color: rgb(0, 86, 143); background-color: rgb(237, 238, 240); text-align: left; width: 139px; height: 14px; padding-left: 1px; padding-top: 1px; left: 1px; top: 1px;">
       Module Name
   </div>
```

I tried like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("div"))
    .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[20]/div[2]"))
    .click();
```

Thanks for all, for ur valuable suggestions.But, Still not able to click.Is there any compatibility or Installation issues can effect this??
   Please see the output to understand the issue better.

Getting Output like this :

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit) 
2.44.0.0 
Listening on port 41280 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Latest
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == /html/body/div[8]/div[1] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Comment: Did you try :   driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[20]/div[2]")).click();

Comment: No need to use "DIV" tag to find element , see my answer I posted that code will help you to get module name.

Comment: I tried the above one,till not working.

Comment: Not that. Please try as per my answer code :                                 driver.switchTo().frame(0);
 String data = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[20]/div[2]")).getText().toString();
 System.out.println(data);

Comment: Tried but getting "NoSuchElementException"

Comment: Then may be xpath is incorrect. Also try to use wait once frame found.

Answer (score 0):

Since the div you want to click is in an `iframe`, you'll need to first switch to it. Unfortunately, the frame has no `id`, you'll need to [find it by its index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3681457/314291) on the page (zero based). Unfortunately, there don't seem to be any remarkable features of the div, other than the content. Here's a simplified `findElement`:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(., 'Module Name')]")).click();
```

I've assumed the first `frame / iframe` on the page - adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Following code running for me as per your requirement :

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(0);
 String data = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[20]/div[2]")).getText().toString();
 System.out.println(data);
```

**Output will be** : Module Name

Note : You can correct xpath if you are taking incorrect. Also replace your frame index if require.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `html` snippet you have provided, I suspect the frame itself is disabled and not able to accept any UI interaction. There some other action needs to happen to enable the frame in order to interact with it(may be click on something). If you have that enable with a valid selector you can perform a click.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[".='Module Name'"]).click();
```

You also want to make sure that target `frame` is the correct one with index `0` in this case. Or find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474978/selenium-webdriver-does-not-find-element-by-xpath) how to identify `frame` with `xpath`