# How can I select not unique element with Selenium WebDriver (inside an iframe)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select page element with no unique id or class. Let it be radiobutton on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio) page. When I try to use name to find the radiobutton

```
var radioButton = driver.FindElements(By.Name("gender"))[1];
radioButton.Click();
```

Visual Studio returns me "An unhandled exception of type System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll".

Timeout was added to make sure that page is fully loaded. But that was not the solution.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

I tried to avoid XPath usage but that didn't work either and [another exception occurred](https://www.screencast.com/t/juqvH0hT)

```
var radioButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/input[2]"));
radioButton.Click();
```

So I'm trying to figure out:

1. What is the proper way to select the radiobutton in this case?
2. How to get rid of OutOfRange exception?
3. Why XPath didn't work in this case?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the html sample is not the all html, check if this is inside `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: @inmydelorean, check this http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2014/04/02/working-with-iframe-elements-and-selenium-2-in-c.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Switching to iframe has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by iframe. Add this code to be able to select elements inside one. If there's no name in corresponding iframe please [see this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549584/selenium-2-switching-focus-to-a-frame-that-has-no-name-id)

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(FrameName);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the page isn't full of radio buttons with the same values, you can use a CSS selector like `input[value='male']`.